# using $(this) in jQuery UI options

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a situation where I need to use $(this) in the options for the position function. I have two dropdowns where each needs to be centered below their corresponding button. I do no want to add extra ID's or anything to the DOM as this code will be used multiple times in one page. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfCNP/27/).

```
$(".dropDown .dialogueBox").position({
    my:        "center top",
    at:        "center bottom",
    of:         $(this).parent().children(".drop-button"),
    collision: "none"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through each element and then you will have access to `$(this)`:

```
$(".dropDown .dialogueBox").each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    that.position({
        my:        "center top",
        at:        "center bottom",
        of:         that.parent().children(".drop-button"),
        collision: "none"
    });
});
```

Read more about `.each` here:

https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Please, please consider *explaining* why this works in the context of the questioner's problem. Answers consisting of raw code may prove you have mastered the pattern, but the questioner (and future readers) deserve to know *how* this works and *why*.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I think that the code is self-explanatory. I've added some comments though.

Comment: Its okay, I understand why it works. It is very self-explainatory. I will accept when I can! Thankyou